# Execution time and checking stream state in c++

Tags: c++, stream

I am trying to understand streams in C++. I have the following code where I print a message a number of times and I'm trying to find if there is a difference in execution time when checking for a good state or not. I used time of course but I couldn't find a definitive answer since sometimes checking was faster and sometimes it wasn't. My intuition says that since checking is an additional operation it should always take (a slightly) longer time. Is there any actual difference or it is just random?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ostream &out = cout;  //initialize ostream object
    size_t arg = stoul(argv[1]); //convert char to size_t

    for (size_t cnt = 0; cnt != arg; ++cnt)
    {
       // if (out.good()) //check goodbit
            out << "Nr. of command line argument " << argc << '\n';

    }
}
```

Comment: Is not random for sure and should be real fast as it is just comparing a few bits. It should depend on the processor you are using, etc. I'm not sure how did you measure the time?

Comment: The difference might be so small its impossible to say - a big reason is "branch prediction"

Comment: until you have something to show i think this should be closed

Comment: @FranciscoBasadre as I said in my post I used the Linux's time command to measure time. The difference was small indeed but the fact that confuses me is that there was no faster choice (even by a little bit), and some times checking was faster and others it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer to your question it is extremely hard in practice to measure the difference. It's just one comparison (the *if*) vs. giving up execution to the OS for I/O and communicating with hardware.

There are multiple layers of abstraction when it comes to printing, from buffering to branch prediction. The actual impact depends on multiple factors. Even multiple runs of exactly the same program will exhibit execution time variation.

You would need to devise a careful and clever experiment to measure the effect of the check reliably.

The take out for your problem here is, that most certainly, the difference is below your testing accuracy and probably below the execution noise. On top of that CPU architecture can actually eliminate the difference, keywords are: *pre-fetching*, *branch prediction* and (in)famous *speculative execution*.